# Shuffle a deck of cards, somehow crashes?

Tags: c, shuffle

so i've come pretty far with a project im making, its basically where it writes all the cards in a deck (which works fine) but when i try to shuffle them, it crashes, i dont actually know whats wrong with it, because it shuffles some of the cards(like 3), then crashes.
Also, do by now, i've only done it for 12 of the cards, is there any easy way of doing it.

Here's my code so far

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ACE 14
#define JACK 11
#define QUEEN 12
#define KING 13

int main()

{
    int cards[14];
    int temp;
    int i;
    int random;
    int j;
    char *color[] = { "Heart","Diamond","Spade","Clubs"};

    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
            cards[i] = i + 1;
            switch (cards[i]) {
            case ACE: printf("Ace");
                break;
            case JACK: printf("Jack");
                break;
            case QUEEN: printf("Queen");
                break;
            case KING: printf("King");
                break;
            default: printf("%d", cards[i]);
            }
            if (j == 0) {
                printf(" of %s\n", color[0]);
            }
            else;
            if (j == 1) {
                printf(" of %s\n", color[1]);
            }
            else;
            if (j == 2) {
                printf(" of %s\n", color[2]);
            }
            else;
            if (j == 3) {
                printf(" of %s\n", color[3]);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n----------------------------\n");
    srand(time(NULL));

//The above works fine, its below where the problem is

    for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        random = (rand() % 13 + 1);
        temp = cards[i];
        cards[i] = cards[random];
        cards[random] = temp;
    }
    char *testcolor[64];
    char m;
    for (i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        m = rand() % 4;
        *testcolor = color[i];
        color[i] = color[m];
        color[m] = *testcolor;

        for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
            printf("%d %s\n", cards[i], color[i]);
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;


}
```

So, as you see, i dont want any "duplicates" which should be in order i guess, but i want the program to print out every card but randomly, just like a machine.

I really appreciate any help because im struggling so bad right now.

Comment: What have you learnt from your debugging efforts?

Comment: `for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
            printf("%d %s\n", cards[i], color[i]);` index of color is 0..3

Comment: Yeah i know the index is [0] to [3] , but i want it to loop a random color  for every number continiousely, cant you help me out a bit better than that?

Comment: Actually create the 52 cards then  do shuffle .

Comment: @chux, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Your code should work (although not very good style) up to the point where you access out of bounds as BLUEPIXY pointed out

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

**Code for shuffling the colors**

You have mixed the code for shuffling the colors and printing the cards. Separate them. Also, the maximum value of the index needs to be `3`, not `13`.

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            //  ^^ Needs to be 4, not 14.
   m = rand() % 4;
   *testcolor = color[i];
   color[i] = color[m];
   color[m] = *testcolor;
}
```

Also, it's not clear to me why you need:

```
char* testcolor[64];
```

You are using it as a temporary variable while swapping pointers. It can just be:

```
char* testcolor;
```

and then, the swapping code needs to be changed to:

```
testcolor = color[i];
color[i] = color[m];
color[m] = testcolor;
```

**Code for printing**

You need two loops, not one loop. You need one index for the cards and another index for the colors.

```
for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      printf("%d %s\n", cards[i], color[j]);
   }
}
```

**Others**

You have defined `m` to be of type `char`. I get the following warning from `gcc`:

```
warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
```

It can be

```
int m;
```

to avoid that warning.

In the loop that you use for shuffling the cards, you have:

```
for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
```

It doesn't have to but it can be:

```
for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying!

Geat help, but what im missing is that i want all the cards to be completely random when generating them, now its printing out a random order but every duece, three, and four are together, so i want it lets say 2 of clubs, 9 of diamonds and not 2,2,2,2  8,8,8,8.

Comment: @Williamhart, are you allowed to use `struct`s? If you are, then create a `struct` that captures both the card and the color. Define a deck of cards as 52 of those `struct`s. Then shuffle the deck.